# Fluid layout to already written code

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I almost finished the code and I realized it's not a fluid layout and I don't know how to do that without changing too much. My site has no menus or whatever, just some textareas and a few buttons.

Is there a specific code for such?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PfJy9/) `enter code here`

Thank you!

Comment: Can you make a fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net )?Cannot help without seeing your present code

Comment: Are you using a framework, like bootstrap etc?

Comment: no, just html and css. i'm new to this :)

Comment: Do you want every element to fit within window width?

Comment: yes. everything should fit within window width.. should work in all browsers too. Minimal resolution is 1024x768

Comment: Fluid layout has all widths and heights set as a percentage or ems within your stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

simply add:

```
textarea, input{
    margin:10px auto !important;
    width:100% !important;
    }
```

to your css stylesheet. Also set a max-width to the parent div class for a good UI (only if you wish not to keep it 100% width for screens which has resolutions 1200px or higher.

For radio buttons, use classes in them, using those classes you can specify the width as you wish.

check **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/codeMonk/PfJy9/1/)**

Comment: looks good. the right margin is ok, but the left one isn't.  i have to get to this: http://i.imgur.com/oAR3GkO.jpg

Comment: In that case, you will have to use either table or 2 sets of div. Table is prettymuch straight forward deal but for 2 div classes, the left one which will keep the labels 'e.g. : Basic function and Scope *', set width to that div class. on the right, you have your input and textarea. now the div class with text will have a width, let's say 20% and input/textarea will have width 80%. but for mobile view, you can use  media-query where you can make it look like the way it is looking right now by keeping both div classes to 100%. do some research and you will get your work done.